# Sending syslog messages to storage pool instead of /var/log/

Tags: rsyslog

I have a centralized syslog server configured and working. It collects logs from a remote device and stores them in `/var/log/<remotehostname>/<logfile>.log`, as it should. The problem is, `/var/log` is very small, and I will eventually have multiple systems sending logs, so I need to store them on a larger device.

In `rsyslog.conf`, I have attempted to specify a different directory in which to send the logs, but upon restarting `rsyslog`, no log files show up in that directory. This directory is located on a 1TB storage device (sdb) which is mounted under `/mnt/`. I then tried to send them to a directory on the same device as `/var/log` (sda), but no logs showed up there either. Permissions for these directories are the same as the directory which gets created under `/var/log`.

TL;DR Need to send log files to storage device, not `/var/log`.

Any idea what I could be missing? Thanks.

Comment: First, when is "first syslog use" and "storage device available"? I think that "first syslog use" comes first, and `rsyslog` fails back to its defaults. Second, unless you share your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` we can't even guess.

Answer (score 0):

Change the /var/log directory into a soft symlink pointing to a folder on your larger device. Just mv the current log directory to the side,

```
mv /var/log /var/log.old
```

and then make a soft symlink

```
ln -s [/path/to/folder/on/large/storage] /var/log
```

and then your log files should be recreated. It's a work around so you don't have to point your logs to a different path.

I will use this trick if I need to scp a file from a server and I don't have permissions for it, but I do have root permissions.

I will create a soft symlink in my home directory pointing to the file I want to scp. That way I can retrieve it using

```
scp server:~/file .
```